# 403.14 - Forbidden when controller name and controller directory name is same in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, .net-4.5, asp.net-web-api2

I have below code where my controller name is Customer and it is part of the Customer directory in my web api 2 project. It seems that IIS doeasn't allow me to use same directory name and controller name as it is throwing error 403 for get call (https://hostname:443/myapp/customers). I think this will not be a problem after deploying the code but in order to debug on my local machine how can I make this working on my local?

```
[RoutePrefix(RoutePrefix)]
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    const string RoutePrefix = @"customers";

    private readonly ICustomersData _customersData;

    public CustomersController(ICustomersData customersData
    {
        _customersData = customersData
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get Customers
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Customers</returns>
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer[]))]
    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers()
    {
        var customers = _customersData.GetCustomers();

        return Ok(customers);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using a different name for the customer folder?

Comment: This code has some screwy stuff.  the constructor has no closing parenthesis.  The one statement in that constructor has a ";=".  What is that?  I do not recognize it.  How did this even compile?

Comment: When are you getting this error ? In trying to access one of the APIs methods ?

Comment: @DavidG That can be easy fix but as I said this will not be issue when I deploy the code but only in local IIS hits the directory name instead of controller so I do not want to use different name.

Comment: @Anon316 It is just typo as I have renamed the actual names!

Comment: @Veverke I am getting this error when I access https://{hostname}:443/myapp/customers

Comment: Your error doesn't make any sense.  You shouldn't be getting a 403, you'd get a 404 if there was something amiss with your routing.  It's far more likely that your authentication is not properly configured locally.

Comment: I may be wrong, but does it make sense in asp.net web api to access a control without specifying the api method ? I mean this is not MVC (is there a default route in web api ? ) - what do you get if you access https://{hostname}:443/myapp/customers/GetCustomers ?

Comment: @Vererke I find it more interesting that "api" is missing from his route.

Comment: @DavidL Why would it matter if that is missing from the route?

Comment: Because the DEFAULT routing for web api includes "/api" as a part of the route.  He hasn't shown us his webapiconfig, so for the time being, it's possible to conclude that the url simply doesn't match his routing.

Comment: @David L
HTTP Error is: 403.14 - Forbidden - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: @Vereke yes you can customize the route as you want using RoutePrefix attribute (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). Note: everything else is working fine besides this Get colloection scenario.

Comment: @seUser The routing system always assumes that existing files and folders will be used in preference to routed URLs. You could try specifying `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` in your route configuration.

Comment: What returns if you try .../customers/GetCustomers ? (I was not talking about RoutePrefix, rather Route (I think from System.http.net like [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#why))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The routing system checks the file system to see if a URL matches a file/folder on the disk. If it finds a match, the routing is ignored and the request bypassed any route entries so that the file will be served directly. This is important for static HTML, JS, images etc.

So in this case, the controller folder matches the URL and tried to server the contents of the directory instead. To fix this you can set the [`RouteExistingFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property to `true` in your routing config:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidG for giving the perfect solution that I was looking for!